# Prestashop 1.6.1.4 SEo & Firendly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, prestashop

I'm using PS 1.6.1.4 I've been trying for weeks to get my website URL from www.youname.com/ecommerce to www.yourname.com without any success. The friendly url doesn't seem to regenerate a .htaccess

Can someone please post an example of an .htaccess redirect for www.yourname.com/ecommerce to www.yourname.com

Kinds regards,

Comment: Can you check your `.htaccess` file rights to be sure that Prestashop can edit it. Also try to save your Friendly URL configuration two times (Press "save", the page will reload and press "save" again) sometimes you need to save it two times for it to edit the `.htaccess` file (yeah a mysterious bug).

Comment: If it doesn't work, please edit your question including your current `.htaccess` and I will edit it in an answer.

Comment: Well in the Prestashop htaccess it says at the begining " # ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution .... but I did tried to save the friendly URL l twice like you suggested it still the same... I have No Idea what's going on ...I'm pretty new to PS

Comment: Could you please post your `.htaccess` file?!

Comment: Hi @FlorianLemaitre sorry I was away for a few days please find the htaccess below:

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on  # Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>              #If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /ecommerce/index.php?controller=404

Comment: I couldn't correctly arrange them since stackoverflow has limited number for text.

Comment: You can edit your question to add this file.